# Fetch sempre retorna "TypeError: Body has already been consumed." , como corrigir?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Estou utilizando a função `fetch` abaixo:

```js
var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2";

fetch(url).then(function(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    alert("Response not ok" + response.statusText);
    throw new Error(response.statusText);
  } else {
    alert(" Response Swal  Json:" + response.json());
  }

  return response.json();
}).catch(function(error) {
  alert("DeuErro -> " + error);

  swal.showValidationError(
    'Erro: ' + error
  )
})
```

Porém ela sempre dispara o erro:

> TypeError: Body has already been consumed.

O que poderia estar ocorrendo?
Quais as formas de corrigir?

Comment: Obs.: No modal do snippet que utilizou para inserir o código existe o botão "Organizar". Utilize-o para formatar corretamente os códigos antes de criar a pergunta para facilitar a leitura dos códigos.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @Woss, não conhecia esse botão

Comment: Dentro do `else`, você já consome o corpo da resposta quando faz `response.json()`; quando você tenta retornar o mesmo valor, já não haverá conteúdo para ser consumido. Por que não atribui isso a uma variável e a reutiliza nesses dois lugares?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O método `response.json` irá retornar uma nova promessa, então precisa lidar com ela corretamente. O mais fácil é tratá-la com `then` encadeados:

```js
var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2";

fetch(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }

    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error("DeuErro -> " + error);
  })
```

Assim, a promessa retornada por `response.json` será processada e o corpo da resposta será passada ao próximo `then` já tratado como JSON.

Uma forma equivalente (e menos encadeada) seria utilizando o `async/await`:

```js
async function get_user_details(id) {
  const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`;
  const response = await fetch(url);
  
  return await response.json();
}

get_user_details(2).then(user => {
  console.log(user);
})
```